# Redeploy to Heroku without committing

Tags: heroku

Asset sync failed while pushing to Heorku. How would I redeploy or essentially re-run the scripts that are run upon pushing without committing and pushing new code.

Answer (score -1):

You can just run the asset_sync rake task manually `heroku run rake assets:sync` - it's detailed in the asset_sync setup https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync